# Scale Dependant Visibility bug

Tags: qgis, scale, visibility

***QGIS 2.18.5***

No matter what I do, if I set minimum visibility to 1,000,000 and max to 400,000 click apply and re-open properties, the max 'resets' itself to 100,000. Visa versa if I set min to 400,000 and max to 100,000,000 - the same occurs again. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** **EDIT** **: It is now fixed in 2.18.9

---

It is a bug
 [Layer "Scale dependent visibility" doesn't work anymore since 2.16](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15463)

PS: I now have a script that backups my project each time I open it should I have the bad idea of touching a layer's property, as the value of 100,000 will be saved to the QGS project...